# What causes the result of "confirmed" to change from "finalized" to something else?

Tags: solana-program, transactions

I have a solana program that has the following two instructions.

1. an instruction that writes a record to the PDA
2. an instruction that fails if this record exists and succeeds if it does not.

If 2 -> 1 is executed quickly with little time interval, the "confirmed" commitment will succeed, but the "finalized" commitment will fail with a non-negligible probability.

What causes the result of "confirmed" to change from "finalized" to something else? Is it possible to prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

Finalized is the last status of a transaction. I'm not sure what you mean by "finalized" to something else? If you're asking how the status is determined then finalized is confirmed with 31+ block atop of its submission block.

You can deterministically execute instructions in order by putting them in the same transaction.

Comment: If I send tx and immediately do confirmTransaction with the commitment: "confirmed" option, it succeeds, but if I wait for the "finalized" phase and confirm tx again, it finally fails sometimes.

I would like to know if it is possible to solve a situation where the structure of the service does not allow sending two instructions to one tx.